# Failing "layout_links_spec" integration tests during Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the Ruby on Rails Tutorial for Rails 3, located here:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org

I am at this section of the tutorial:

[http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:integration_tests](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec%3aintegration_tests)

All of my pages render as expected at this point; e.g., I can hit `http://localhost:3000/about` and see the about page of the sample application, with the expected title ("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About").  Yet the integration tests from this section keep failing.

Here is my layout_links_spec.rb:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do

  it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
    get '/'
    response should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
  end

  it "should have a Contact page at '/contact'" do
    get '/contact'
    response should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
  end

  it "should have an About page at '/about'" do 
    get '/about'
    response should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
  end

  it "should have a Help page at '/help'" do
    get '/help'
    response should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
  end
end
```

When I run tests with `rspec spec/` or via `autotest`, I get the following test failures:

```
    ........FFFF

    Failures:

      1) LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
         Failure/Error: response should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
           expected following output to contain a <title>Home</title> tag:
           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
           <html><body><p>LayoutLinks</p></body></html>
         # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      2) LayoutLinks should have a Contact page at '/contact'
         Failure/Error: response should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
           expected following output to contain a <title>Contact</title> tag:
           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
           <html><body><p>LayoutLinks</p></body></html>
         # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      3) LayoutLinks should have an About page at '/about'
         Failure/Error: response should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
           expected following output to contain a <title>About</title> tag:
           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
           <html><body><p>LayoutLinks</p></body></html>
         # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

      4) LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/help'
         Failure/Error: response should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
           expected following output to contain a <title>Help</title> tag:
           <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
           <html><body><p>LayoutLinks</p></body></html>
         # ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

    Finished in 0.23497 seconds
    12 examples, 4 failures

    Failed examples:

    rspec ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:5 # LayoutLinks should have a Home page at '/'
    rspec ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:10 # LayoutLinks should have a Contact page at '/contact'
    rspec ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:15 # LayoutLinks should have an About page at '/about'
    rspec ./spec/requests/layout_links_spec.rb:20 # LayoutLinks should have a Help page at '/help'
```

...note that the response shown in the test failures appears to indicate that I'm getting a mock/stubbed response.  **I believe that this is my issue, but I don't know why it is happening.**

Finally, here is my environment:

Gatito:sample_app abrown$ gem list

```
    *** LOCAL GEMS ***

    abstract (1.0.0)
    actionmailer (3.0.9)
    actionpack (3.0.9)
    activemodel (3.0.9)
    activerecord (3.0.9)
    activeresource (3.0.9)
    activesupport (3.0.9)
    arel (2.0.10)
    autotest (4.4.6)
    autotest-fsevent (0.2.4)
    autotest-growl (0.2.9)
    autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
    builder (2.1.2)
    bundler (1.0.15)
    configuration (1.2.0)
    diff-lcs (1.1.2)
    erubis (2.6.6)
    heroku (2.3.3)
    i18n (0.5.0)
    launchy (0.4.0)
    mail (2.2.19)
    mime-types (1.16)
    nokogiri (1.4.6)
    polyglot (0.3.1)
    rack (1.2.3)
    rack-mount (0.6.14)
    rack-test (0.5.7)
    rails (3.0.9)
    railties (3.0.9)
    rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
    rdoc (3.6.1)
    rest-client (1.6.3)
    rspec (2.6.0)
    rspec-core (2.6.4)
    rspec-expectations (2.6.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.6.0)
    rspec-rails (2.6.1)
    sequel (3.20.0)
    sinatra (1.0)
    spork (0.9.0.rc8)
    sqlite3 (1.3.3)
    sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
    sys-uname (0.8.5)
    taps (0.3.23)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
    thor (0.14.6)
    treetop (1.4.9)
    tzinfo (0.3.28)
    webrat (0.7.1)
    ZenTest (4.5.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I typed in the tests above myself.  When I re-copied/pasted the tests directly from the tutorial, they began passing.  I was mystified, as everything looked identical at a glance.  But after running a `diff`, I realized that for each test, I had typed:

```ruby
response should
```

...but that I should have typed:

```ruby
# Note the "."
response.should
```

After making this correction to each test, they all pass as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the exact same error, but the cause was forgetting to include `render_views` line in the test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do

    render_views

    describe "GET 'home'" do
        it "should be successful" do
            get 'home'
            response.should be_success
        end
    end
```